# kubernetes statefulsets index/ordinal exposed in template

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Statefulsets direct kubectl/kubernetes to create pods with an index or ordinal following the pod name.  If the entity has a name of redis for example and the replication count is 3, then we will get redis-0, redis-1 and redis-2.  Is there some way to get access to the index or ordinal?  It would be very useful to pass to the startup script for a container.  It would be nice if it were available in the downward api.  It would be really really nice to use it when trying to line up PVC's to PV's.

> Is it possible that there is some secret template variable for this?

Note that I have found a way around it.  I am using a script for my command and use the hostname to extract it.  But it just seems like a lot of work (and future maintenance).

Comment: Ongoing discussion in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30427

Comment: Still ongoing discussion at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/117986 now , but https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/ provides some workarounds

Answer (score 1):

Eventually this should work by adding to the manifest env (I'm told 1.9 onwards but not confirmed yet):

```
   - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
     valueFrom:
       fieldRef:
         fieldPath: metadata.annotations['spec.pod.beta.kubernetes.io/statefulset-index']
```

For now you can 'hack' it like you did using script or using lifecycle events like following:

```
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command:
            - "/bin/sh"
            - "-c"
            - "export KAFKA_BROKER_ID=${HOSTNAME##*-}"
```

Comment: No a correct workaround if the env varaible must be set before the entry point is called: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-lifecycle-hooks/ *There is no guarantee that the hook will execute before the container ENTRYPOINT*